# bash printf backslash then new line

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create this from bash into a c header

```
#define XXXXX \

 "id title\n" \ 

 "1  developer\n" \

the script is 

FORMAT="  \"%-4s  %-32s\\\n"

printf "$FORMAT" "id" "title\\n\"" >> $FILE

printf "$FORMAT" "1" "Developer\\n\"" >> $FILE
```

the result would be

```
"id    title\n"                        \n  "1     Developer\n"                              \n
```

when I change 
`FORMAT="%-4s  %-32s \\ \n"`

I get

```
"id    title\n"                           \ 
"1     Developer\n"                       \
```

and gcc start to complain the extra space after `\`

It seems that the `\\` would be interpreted more than once if there is no space.

without using
`FORMAT="%-4s  %-32s \\"`

```
printf "$FORMAT" "id" "title\\n\"" >> $FILE

printf "\n" >> $FILE
...
```

Is there any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use hexadecimal escape sequences:

```
FORMAT="%-4s %-32s \x5C\n"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  The question might be a little distraction but the problem lies how to output a backslash then followed by a newline

Answer (score 0):

shell treats double quote and single quote differently.

Don's use double quote here:

```
FORMAT="%-4s %-32s \\n"
```

Use single quote like this and avoid escaping:

```
FORMAT='%-4s %-32s \n'
```

OR for printing literal backslash and newline:

```
FORMAT='%-4s %-32s \\\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I still need the backslash to be generated in the file, also I prefer no space after \ to avoid compiler warnings

Comment: I just updated the post, the output format is for macro definition like "#define xxxxx \{newline} "id name\n" \{newline} "1 me\n" \{newline}

Comment: You're welcome, hope these examples will give you clear understanding how escaping and echoing backslash works in shell.